# Represent Free Form Object in JPA

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a data model that depicts a free form field that can contain anything. In other words, it can contain primitive as well as objects.

How can I implement the same in Java/JPA stack?

Using `spring-data-jpa`,`SpringBoot`..

**Sample 1**

```
"value" : "newvalue"
```

**Sample 2**

```
"value" : {
     "@type" : "IPAddress",
     "IP" : "127.0.0.1"
}
```

Comment: If you cannot restrict the value's type in any way then you will at least need to make sure the objects are `Serializable`. JPA can handle `Serializable`s of any type. However, you may want to reconsider the data model that is so 'flexible'.

Comment: Alternatively, if you want to store it in human-readable form, see [this tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-persist-json-object). You might also want to use a dedicated JSON database type if your DB offers one

Comment: @crizzis, Thanks do you think it supports non json representation as well as indicated in question for Sample 1?

Comment: @JimmyB Thanks. Can you please point me to some resource? I understand the persisted representation should be `Serializable` but confused as how it would look in DB?

Comment: @Divs If JPA does not know how to map an object to/from the DB but the object implements `Serializable`, JPA will store the serialized object as a binary/byte array column type.

Comment: Instead of a `Map`, you should be able to use the opaque `JsonNode` type (see [here](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-json-to-jsonnode) for an example). This way, you'll be able to represent JSON objects as well as JSON primitives